# SignalR 2.3.0 not working after update jQuery 3.x

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr

I have a Grid page which is showing the users, if the row is being edited by someone.
When I go to the Edit page it goes to the editInProgress C# function on the server, but it does not send it back to the other clients somehow. The code has not changed on that part.
And when I open this particularly record, it will lock buttons and so fort.

The issue here is that it was **perfectly working with signalR 2.3.0 and jQuery 2.2.4**. 
But somehow it is **not working after updating to jQuery 3.0.0-3.3.1**.

So it must have to do with the jQuery 3 update somehow or that SignalR 2.3.0 does not support version 3 yet. 
What I think is very strange, while it is out some time already.
I have seen many ideas and possible solutions, but nothing is working for me.

I struggled for this a long time now, but I solved my issue by don't using the [generated proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#cantusegenproxy) way by setting up signalR.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my question with the answer.